# NullPointerException in onLoaderFinished using SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception, android-cursorloader

I have switched from a `ResourceCursorAdapter` where I used `newView` and `bindView` to a `SimpleCursorAdapter` where I am using only the `getView` method.

Now I have an error in `onLoaderFinished`. Although it gives me `NullPointerException` on `adapter.swapCursor(cursor)` both my adapter and cursor object are **NOT null**.  I will post all of my code below. Any help is greatly appreciated (not got much hair left to pull out).

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ContactSelect extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
private static final int LOADER_ID = 1;
private MyAdapter adapter;
private ListView list;
private View row;
private SparseBooleanArray checkedState = new SparseBooleanArray();

@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi" })
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_select);       

    adapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.contacts_select_row, null, null, null, 0);     

    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);        

    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);                 

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));    

}   

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    final String projection[] = new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
    final Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

    final String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1" + 
    " AND " + ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " =1";

    final String order = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    final CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(this, uri, projection, selection, null, order);

    return loader;      
}

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    for(int i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++){
        checkedState.put(i, false);
    }

    adapter.swapCursor(cursor);                 
}

public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    adapter.swapCursor(null);       
}

private class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements OnClickListener{
    private CheckBox markedBox;
    private TextView familyText;
    private Context context;
    private Cursor cursor;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,
            int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);

        this.context = context;
        this.cursor = getCursor();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup group) {

        final LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = li.inflate(R.layout.contacts_select_row, group, false);

        view.setTag(cursor.getPosition());
        view.setOnClickListener(this);

        familyText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.contacts_row_family_name);
        markedBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.contacts_row_check);
        familyText.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));

        boolean currentlyChecked = checkedState.get(cursor.getPosition());
        markedBox.setChecked(currentlyChecked);     


        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

        return super.getView(position, view, group);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        int rowId = (Integer)view.getTag();
        Log.d("OnClick", String.valueOf(rowId));
        boolean currentlyChecked = checkedState.get(rowId);
        markedBox.setChecked(!currentlyChecked);
        checkedState.put(rowId, !currentlyChecked);
        Log.d("checkedState", "checkedState(" + rowId + ") = " + checkedState.get(rowId));
    }       
      }     
}
```

Comment: provide your import statement because exact Cursor package is improted or not

Comment: I have added my imports to the original question

Comment: can you post the logcat too? I just need to know if the stack ends at the point you mentioned or goes further

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A call of the `swapCursor` method of the `SimpleCursorAdapter` class will trigger a function which maps the column names from the `String` array provided to the constructor(the 4th parameter) to an array of integers representing the columns indexes. As you pass `null` in the constructor of `MyAdapter` for the `String` array representing the columns names from the cursor, this will throw a `NullPointerException` later when the `swapCursor` will try to make the mapping(the `NullPointerException` should appear in a method `findColumns`, which is the actual method that uses the column names `String` array).

The solution is to pass a valid `String` array, you may also want to do this for the `int` array representing the ids for the views in which to place the data:

```
String[] from = {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
int[] to = {R.id.contacts_row_family_name, R.id.contacts_row_check};
adapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.contacts_select_row, null, from, to, 0);
```

I don't know what you are trying to do but your implementation of the `getView` method is not quite right:

You do the normal stuff for the `getView` method(creating layouts, searching views, binding data) and then you simply return the view from the superclass(?!?), you'll probably just see the default layout with nothing in it.

The way you wrote the `getView` method is not very efficient, you may want to look into view recycling and the view holder pattern.

`cursor.getPosition()` will not do what you want as you don't move the cursor to the correct position. By default cursors based adapters will do this for you in the `getView` method, but, as you overrode the method it's your job to move the cursor's position.

You should leave the `getView`  method and use the two methods `newView` and `bindView` as they offer a better separation of the logic.

Answer (score 2):

adapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.contacts_select_row, null, null, null, 0);

and your MyAdapter class you are passing null cursor

```
  public MyAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,
            int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);

        this.context = context;
        this.cursor = getCursor();
    }
```

Comment: Hi there,Thanks for responding.

The reason for teh null cursor pass is because I won't have a cursor object until the LoaderManager finishes. I should point out that this code worked perfectly fine while using ResourceCursorAdapter